# Is it important to assign CSS injector and JS injector code snippets to specific pages instead of site wide?

Tags: theming

**Is it important to assign CSS injector and JS injector code snippets to specific pages instead of site wide?**

If the code is a few lines, is there a REAL performance benefit to assign css and JS to only some pages?

Or does it only matter for very large code?

I'm just wondering if it's over kill to target the specific pages all the time?

An example code snippet combo I'm using is the first word for JS

```
$('p').each(function() {
var word = $(this).html();
var index = word.indexOf(' ');
if(index == -1) {
    index = word.length;
}
$(this).html('<span class="first-word">' + word.substring(0, index) +    '</span>' + word.substring(index, word.length));
});
```

And CSS:

```
.first-word { font-style:italic; }
```

So less than 10 lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

For those amount of lines, it's no biggie, specially if you're caching, as those lines gets cached as HTML.

An alternative, the good practice, would be to add the css to your theme's **style.css** file and the JS to your **theme.info** file. That way you can aggregate and compress them along with your other files.

Aggregating and compressing makes a huge difference. You should do that if you aren't already. (speaking of all your css and js files).

[image]

Comment: So would it be good practice to prototype with JS injector and CSS injector, and once the site is in production move the code to outside files? What about saving some important rules as features for future quick use?

Comment: some people consider printing css and js into your html as bad practice, but it's actually no big deal as long as the code is very small. Feel free to use the injector for prototyping. `What about saving some important rules as features for future quick use` what rules are you referring to? Rules module?

Comment: I mean bundling up css injector and js injector with all settings into one features module, that way no need to modify css files for other sites, all my sites are based on boostrap

Comment: I have about 600 css rules in a css injector file.. It gets aggregated fine. Or so I think. Maybe not?